# Embed spreadsheet in a powerpoint in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, excel, powerpoint

I want to embed specific cells from a spreadsheet in a powerpoint presentation.  I have seen this done before with macros (I think), but I have never done it myself.  I have done a little googling and am coming up with 50 solutions.  Can someone help me narrow it down.

The big gotcha here is that both of these files will be in one folder in a document library in a sharepoint site.  The other gotcha, which is kind of a given, is that I want the ppt to update to latest excel data when it is opened.

Comment: A spreadsheet... inside a powerpoint... inside SharePoint?

Comment: Kit, that would be correct....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is much simpler than I thought.  Here is the answer for anyone else who is attempting this:

1. Make sure the files are in their final folders you want them in
2. Open the files
3. Select the Cells you want to display in the ppt - Ctrl - C to copy
4. Edit -> Paste Special in the ppt slide you want the cells to display on
5. Paste as a MS Excel Worksheet Object AND select the "As a Link" checkbox on the left
6. Size it however you want
7. Save the ppt
8. Each time you open the ppt you select "update links" and the ppt gets the latest data from the xls
9. The sharepoint part is no big deal, it appears to just work like it would if the files were local

These instructions are for Office 2003, they are likely similiar for other officer versions.